# IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu not called by Shell (Win10)

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, contextmenu, shell-extensions

I have a class called `ValidatorContextMenuHandler` that implements the `IShellExtInit` and `IContextMenu` interfaces.

My DLL is being referenced in the Registry, and gets loaded into Windows Explorer correctly. I check this by creating MessageBoxes whenever a method is being called. When I right click on a file, I also get notified of my `ContextMenuHandler` being instantiated. So, `IShellExtInit::Initialize()` is indeed being called (twice, actually). My implementation of `IShellExtInit::Initialize()` looks like the following:

```cpp
IFACEMETHODIMP ValidatorContextMenuHandler::Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFolder, IDataObject* pdtobj, HKEY hKeyProgID)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"ContextMenuHandler Initialized!", L"Notice", MB_OK);
    return S_OK;
}
```

However, after that nothing happens. `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu()` is never being called, and I cannot find the cause. The first line of `QueryContextMenu()` should bring up a MessageBox, but it never gets to that point in the first place.

My implementation of the method looks like the following:

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP ValidatorContextMenuHandler::QueryContextMenu(HMENU hMenu, UINT indexMenu, UINT idCmdFirst, UINT idCmdLast, UINT uFlags)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"QUERYING CONTEXT MENU", L"ValidatorContextMenuHandler::QueryContextMenu()", MB_OK);

    //...Removed the unnecessary code after this, so that the post doesn't get too long
}
```

There are no compiling errors, and the DLL I tested on is the newest version (unloaded DLL with `regsvr32 /u`, restarted Windows Explorer, loaded DLL with `regsvr32`).

For those wanting to see my header file:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include<Windows.h>
#include<ShlObj.h>

extern UINT g_cObjCount;

class ValidatorContextMenuHandler : public IShellExtInit, IContextMenu
{
protected:
    DWORD m_ObjRefCount;
    ~ValidatorContextMenuHandler();

public:
    ValidatorContextMenuHandler();

    //IUnknown Methods
    ULONG __stdcall AddRef();
    ULONG __stdcall Release();
    HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject);

    //IShellExtInit Methods
    IFACEMETHODIMP Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFolder, IDataObject* pdtobj, HKEY hKeyProgID);

    //IContextMenu Methods
    IFACEMETHODIMP GetCommandString(UINT_PTR idCmd, UINT uFlags, UINT* pwReserved, LPSTR pszName, UINT cchMax);
    STDMETHODIMP InvokeCommand(LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO pici); 
    STDMETHODIMP QueryContextMenu(HMENU hMenu, UINT indexMenu, UINT idCmdFirst, UINT idCmdLast, UINT uFlags); 
};
```

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 2004
Build: 19041.1165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't working. A lot of frustration for nothing.

In my `ValidatorContextMenuHandler.cpp` file, I did a simple mistake. When queried for the `IContextMenu` interface, I accidentally cast `this` to `IClassFactory` when I should cast it to `IContextMenu`. Mistyped it.

**Before:**

```cpp
else if (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IContextMenu))
{
    *ppvObject = (IClassFactory*)this;
    this->AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
```

**After:**

```cpp
else if (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IContextMenu)) 
{
    *ppvObject = (IContextMenu*)this; 
    this->AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: And this is why C-style casts in C++ are dangerous. You should always use C++-style casts. Had you used `static_cast<IClassFactory*>(this)`, your original code would have failed to compile since your class does not derive from `IClassFactory`, so `this` can't be casted to it. C++ casts perform validations that C casts do not.

Comment: Friends don't let friends program in COM without ATL.

Comment: No, this is not the problem for me. And also, you are supposed to cast the pointer to `void *` anyway. Like this: `if( riid == IID_IUnknown  ||
  riid == IID_IShellExtInit ||
  riid == IID_IContextMenu )
 {
  *ppo = (void *)this; ..... }`

Comment: Friends, don't let friends blindly use shortcuts made by other people without understanding how it all works on the lowest level. This path leads to the world akin to "Idiocracy" movie.